# What is the male equivalent of "damsel"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammatical-gender

Is there a male equivalent of "damsel" ?

> **damsel (dam·sel)**
>   *Pronunciation:* /ˈdamzəl/
>
> *noun archaic or literary*
>      a young unmarried woman.

(from [OxfordDictionaries.com](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/damsel))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the male counterpart would be *bachelor*. The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bachelor) notes that the "*Meaning evolved from "knight in training" to "young unmarried man" (early 14c.)*"

Note that in modern English the word *bachelor* can still refer to an unmarried man (although not necessarily a young one).

Comment: Hmmm... Though *"bachelor in distress"* doesn't quite sound as good as *"damsel in distress"*

Comment: Actually, it sounds quite amusing to me...

Comment: @Bjorn: If so, then what about *spinster*?

Comment: @NullUserException "Damsel in distress" sounds good because of the alliteration. Perhaps you need someone to coin a phrase such as  "Bachelor without bravado"

Comment: I would suggest "bachelor in a bind" myself, to go with the "in trouble" theme.

Answer (score 7):

It's amusing to note that, according to [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/damsel), *damsel* also applies to a *young gentleman*:

> **damsel**: A titular designation of a young gentleman; a young man of gentle or noble birth: as, *damsel* Pepin; *damsel* Richard, Prince of
>   Wales.

Even when damsel wasn't an archaic term, *young gentleman* was the best equivalent, as in the title of the Thomas Rowlandson painting "[A college green with a group of damsels and young gentlemen in the foreground, c.1810-15.](http://www.rococo-in-art.org/A-college-green-with-a-group-of-damsels-and-young-gentlemen-in-the-foreground,-c.1810-15.html)"

Comment: I like the idea of a damsel being a young male, even if pretty and useless. It could have its uses in sarcasm, maybe.

Comment: Also, there were (are?) _damsels-errant_, which could have some unfortunate connotations.

Answer (score 5):

A **damsel** implies a **young lady of noble birth** or **a maiden**. The word
comes from the French *Damoiselle* (not in use nowadays, it has a strong Middle-Ages flavour).

The male equivalent of a *damoiselle* in French is *damoiseau*. And *damoiseau* has an entry in both the OED and [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/damoiseau).

Quoting the OED :

> Damoiseau : [a. OF. damoiseau the masculine corresp. to damoisel, damsel.]
>   A young man of gentle birth, not yet made a knight. (Occurring in 15th c. translations from French, and in modern archaists.)

If we do not want to use *damoiseau* in English, the nearest male equivalent seems **the lad** indeed, the word *lad* sounding (at least to me) slightly outdated. 
Lass (feminine of lad) is also given by the OED as a synonym of damsel.

@prash : *Damsel* doesn't imply that the young lady is in distress. Unless specified to be in distress, of course ! *A damsel in distress* is a literary theme that goes way back into Antiquity and revived in the middle-ages.

Comment: Damoiselle is, of course, in use nowadays with the prefix "ma-".

Comment: I did not draw any such implication. I was adding to the comment made by NullUserException: 'Though "bachelor in distress" doesn't quite sound as good as "damsel in distress"'. Perhaps I should have added my comment below his to prevent confusion.

Comment: @Peter Taylor. Madamoiselle has **never** been used in French. We use *mademoiselle* (as a title) or *demoiselle* (as lady). *Damoiselle*, although derived from the same latin root is perceived nowadays as an entirely different word.

Comment: If you ask me, it sounds like the best "translation" of damoiseau into English would be "damso", or maybe "damseau", in analogy with damoiselle->damsel.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go with [lad](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/lad) because it seems to be used in similar kinds of discourse. The trouble is that "a lad in distress" sounds like "Aladdin distress".

Comment: A lad as generally perceived would be too young to be in any real distress.

Comment: @Kris: Nope. "Lad" includes young men. And age has nothing to do with distress.

Answer (score 2):

I would say gentle-man is the masculin equivalent of damsel, because it implies the idea of chevalry, of noble intentions, that goes well with the Middle Ages code of honor. Damsels are in distress and gentlemen are there to save them. Besides, gentlemen also refers to the noble origin, when damsel implies the idea of virginity and innocence.

Answer (score 1):

*Wight* is a near-equivalent, going by the dictionary.  The problem is that *damsel* has heavy connotations of pretty but useless, and (obviously) there are no men who could be described so.

Edit: the word is Anglo-Saxon, and since *man* means pretty much the same, *wight* was never very common. Chambers defines it as "man (archaic or dialect): supernatural being (obs)", the only use I can think of that is not for self-conscious effect (or sub-Tolkien) is Hardy's 'In Time of the Breaking of Nations': "a maid and her wight/ come whispering by".

Comment: Tim, which dictionary did you use? The only meaning of wight I'm familiar with is the one of a supernatural being.

Comment: "Wight" reminds me of the [wights](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Others) from George R.R. Martin's "A Song of Ice and Fire"

Comment: **wight** noun [usu. with adj. ] archaic or dialect.
a person of a specified kind, esp. one regarded as unfortunate : *he always was an unlucky wight*.

Answer (score 0):

> *[**Damsel**](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=don&allowed_in_frame=0)* came from a diminutive of Lat. *dominus*, "lord, head of the house", and hence meant a younger male or female of noble birth.
>
> Although archaic, the [1913 Webster's](http://machaut.uchicago.edu/?action=search&resource=Webster%27s&word=Damsel&quicksearch=on) lists the following examples of its use for young males:
>
> *Damsel Pepin*; *Damsel Richard*, *Prince of Wales*.
>
> But its modern use has been narrowed to an exclusively female designation. Perhaps, considering its etymology and looking for a cognate for males, I might suggest a creative use of the word "[don](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=don)".
>
> ***Don in distress*** could thus have an interesting effect on the reader, which, as a writer, you could employ under poetic license.

From Etymonline

> **don**
> 1520s, from Spanish or Portuguese *don*, title of respect, from Latin *dominus* "lord, master." The university sense is c. 1660, originally student slang; underworld sense is 1952, from Italian *don*, from Late Latin *domnus*, from Latin *dominus*. The fem. form is *Dona* (Spanish/Portuguese), *Donna* (Italian).

[Yahoo! Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090515000138AA6jCss)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: Please explain why "Don in distress" is your answer to the question, beyond just "sounding good".