# Is there a Male suffix equivalent to -et/-ette?

Tags: suffixes, grammatical-gender

I wanted to add a suffix to crone and damsel that would make them masculine without resorting to a male equivalent word, (that's a different question.)

We have the male-to-female conversion example of bachelor → ‎bachelorette

Is there a reverse suffix for traditionally feminine words?

Croner and damseler (following widower ← widow) seems lacking.

Comment: So you are looking for female forms of words like _crone_ and _damsel_ which have only ever been used to specifically describe women? Good luck, there don't seem to be any productive suffixes for such things, and I don't expect them to appear any time soon with the world moving away from using such gender-stereotyping words in general. I _am_ wondering  what a male damsel or crone would be for instance, the concept of _damsel_ or _crone_ being largely linked to a society in which no man could have such a role.

Comment: For a male counterpart to "damsel", see here: [What is the male equivalent of “damsel”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50048) There is no suffix that I know of. In French, *-et* is a masculine suffix (as in the word "valet"); *-ette* is the corresponding feminine suffix.

Comment: I have never heard of **bachelorette**. IFAIK the equivalent word is **spinster**.

Comment: ... although there are connotations in those words meaning "didn't want to marry" and "never was asked to marry". But the trouble with **bachelorette** is it also genderises, as with **actress** who is an **actor**. If a woman does not want to marry, why can't she too be a **bachelor** or a **bachelor girl**?

Comment: No, an actress is an actress. She is not an actor. Not without changing sex, anyway. The reason a woman cannot be a bachelor is that she is a woman.

Comment: @AndrewLeach that's a new one to me, a woman is not an actor. Can I tell "as the actor said to the bishop" jokes in latter day society? By the way, can a man "wash up", or can only a "wife" do that?

Comment: This is a fool's errand, I'm afraid. Bachelorette is not a spinster. It's a single woman who has not **yet** married. I believe the Am TV series may have coined the term.....I like genderizing. I use actress and not actor. And by the way, bachelorette is not a male-to-female conversion. What a thought. That is a transexual, in English....

Comment: @AndrewLeach I’m with the Guardian Style Guide on Actor. https://www.theguardian.com/guardian-observer-style-guide-a

Comment: @Lambie Do you have a source for your differentiation between spinster and bachelorette? How does on distinguish between a *man* who hasn’t married and a man who hasn’t married *yet*?

Comment: Yes... well, I haven't been infected with the political correctness that the Guardian is famous for.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Some women who act call themselves Actresses, but many call themselves actors; per OED Actor- ' A person who acts a part on stage '. Is the OED also too PC?

Comment: OED simply records usage. It makes no judgement call, which means that it's not necessarily a good indicator of the good, poor or indifferent judgement of English speakers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, there are very few words where the male version is derived from the female. For example, [A junior English grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=7S0PAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA25&lpg=PA25) (1902) lists four: *bridegroom*, *drake*, *gander*, and *widower* (but OED does not support the claim that *drake* and *gander* were formed this way).

You already mentioned *widower*, so let's look at *bridegroom*. According to OED, it was formed from brýd + guma. The word *bride* is obviously still in use, but *guma* is not. In Middle English it was spelled [gome](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED19067&egs=all). According to OED:

> After *gome n.<sup>1</sup>* became obsolete in Middle English, the place of *bridegome* was taken in 16th cent. by *bridegrome* , < *grome* , *groom n.<sup>1</sup>* ‘lad’.

Because *gome* is obsolete, as is the sense of *groom* meaning "lad", it's not a great choice.

However, there is another option (not a suffix though) not mentioned by that source. The prefix *man-* is used in several compounds, for example:

- Man nurse
- [Man midwife](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/man-midwife)
- [Man whore](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Manwhore)
- [Man slut](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Man+Slut)
- [Man slag](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=man+slag)

(Note that some of these compounds can be written as [closed or hyphenated](http://blog.sfbar.org/2013/07/31/legal-writing-tip-the-three-types-of-compound-words/) too.)

Interestingly enough, there are some instances already out there for the words you mentioned:

> We haven't seen each other for a couple of years. I am a man-crone.
> <sub>[Hal Crawford on Twitter](https://twitter.com/halcrawford/status/646911235112366081)</sub>

> Still, though, doesn’t the crone get pent up? Who gets the crone’s rocks off? Does she find a man-crone for that?
> <sub>[The Road
> by Anna Bardin](http://www.essayclub.org/essays/road/road-anna-bardin/)</sub>

> It’s got Brandon Flowers as a man-damsel in distress
> <sub>[The Music Video for Brandon Flowers’s “Crossfire” Has Got EVERYTHING](https://nobodyputsbabyinahorner.wordpress.com/2010/07/08/the-music-video-for-brandon-flowerss-crossfire-has-got-everything/)</sub>

> Eugene is mincing away from a small gang of three walkers, a ***Man-Damsel In Distress***.
> <sub>[barnfullawalkers: The Walking Dead, Season 5, Episode 5, “Self Help”](https://barnfullawalkers.com/2014/11/15/the-walking-dead-season-5-episode-5-self-help/)</sub>

---

Yet another option may be to look for synonyms, where the word doesn’t have an etymological connection. Some resources for the words you listed are:

- [What is the male equivalent of "damsel"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/50048/191178)
- [Thesaurus.com: Old person synonyms](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/old%20person)
- [Macmillan Dictionary: Informal and insulting words for old people](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/informal-and-insulting-words-for-old-people)

Comment: A man crone is a curmudgeon, no?

Comment: Aside: "harridan" is gender specific, but is "dotard"?

Answer (score 2):

I know that -Tor indicates a male while -trix denotes female.-Ette is french if I remember...

It appears that in the native french the masculine is -et and the feminine is -ette. Both meaning a smaller form of something else, for example a Cigarette is a smaller cigar. At some point English seemed to pick it up as a term meaning a feminine version of something else as well.

Comment: References would improve this answer.