# Why does using "women" as a modifier work but "men" doesn't?

Tags: word-usage, gender-positive

Chrome's home page tab link for Womens History Month caught my eye today:

> Celebrating women history makers, pioneers and future leaders

Why does this work, if it actually does, and why doesn't the gender inverse work? "Celebrating men history makers" is plain odd to my ear. Is there an implied "who are" in there that's not obvious?

I recognize that using "female" as a noun to *refer* to a woman can sound disrespectful, but when used as a modifier it seems like a different situation. "Celebrating female history makers" sounds much more appropriate.

[image]

Comment: Because it’s the default for a phrase like “history makers, pioneers and future leaders” to refer to a group of all men, maybe occasionally including a few women in addition? It doesn’t sound odd to use “men” in the same way with female-assumed expressions such as “nurse” or “midwife”. For examples see https://english.stackexchange.com/a/421783/191178

Comment: Using your example, the parallel phrase would be "men nurses". That also strikes me as odd.

Comment: There's also a nuance of plurality. A list of corresponding phrases would help with any answer: male nurse, man nurse, men nurses, women firefighters, woman firefighter female firefighter, etc etc

Comment: You're conflating two words of different _types_ there. "Man" and "male" are not usually equivalent in the way they're applied here. Plurality is only peripherally relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are grammatically possible, but using *woman* and *woman* as an appositive is more common than using *man* and *men* in this way. It's hard to answer why this the case; it could be changing patterns of labor for women that brought them into more male-dominated professions, which isn't reciprocal. It could also be that you're more accommodated to hearing *women* used this way, whereas you aren't used to hearing *men* this way.

The Oxford English Dictionary has a fully-fleshed out explanation for *[woman](https://oed.com/view/Entry/229884)* and *women* used in this way. Note that the usage is common enough that the list of examples is not comprehensive:

> C1. b. Appositive, passing into adj.: female.
>
> (a) Prefixed to designations of occupation, employment, or status, esp. those traditionally applied to men, to indicate that the person referred to is a woman, as woman doctor, woman driver, woman friend, woman officer, woman teacher, etc.

It also has an entry for compounds with *[man](https://oed.com/view/Entry/113198)*, but it's more limited, with a list of examples including the unusual *man-cook*, *man dancer*, *man friend*, and *man-nurse*, along with several even more uncommon ones (*man seal*). That indicates the lexicographers didn't view this usage as particularly common:

> C1 b. Appositive, passing into adj.: ‘male’. Occasionally with names of animals. See also man-child n., manservant n., man-midwife n.In plural, frequently with men.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=women%20nurses%2Cmen%20nurses%2Cwomen%20leaders%2Cmen%20leaders%2Cwomen%20teachers%2C%20men%20teachers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwomen%20nurses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20nurses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20leaders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20leaders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20teachers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20teachers%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwomen%20nurses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20nurses%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20leaders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20leaders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwomen%20teachers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmen%20teachers%3B%2Cc0) and other corpus searches can confirm that the versions with *women* are usually used more often than versions with *men*, e.g.:

[image]

Note that *women teachers* and *women leaders* are both used much more, whereas *women nurses* is not. There may be more to dig into with individual collocations.

As for why *woman* and *women* are usually more common, that is possibly due to the shifting socioeconomic status of women in English-speaking places. As women have increasingly worked outside the home, pursued professions, and attained positions of status, *woman* and *women* have been used with professions and other nouns to specify the subset of women in those positions. There has been less social need to use *men* to specify subsets of people in these positions. Perhaps it would lead to a perceived redundancy (*men leaders* specifies most leaders, even today), or perhaps there is less impetus to understand and improve men's participation in professions dominated by women ("[Men nurses](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15238127/)").

So you technically can use *men* in this way, in the sense you can use the noun as an appositive. There are just fewer instances where that usage makes sense.

Comment: Did you mean to say _women_ in the second instance of your opening sentence? You repeated _woman_, but that could've been intentional and I misunderstand your meaning.